# Symbolic matrix power series in Theano

Tags: python, linear-algebra, theano

Let's say I have a 2d tensor `A`.  I'd like to symbolically compute `Apow`, the power series of `A`, which is a 3d tensor defined as follows:

```
Apow = [I, A, A^2, A^3, ..., A^k]
```

where `A^2` means `A.dot(A)` (i.e. the power series is defined with respect to the dot product rather than element-wise).  `k` is a symbolic scalar that specifies the length of the series.

How can I implement this in Theano?  It seems like the solution would be based on `scan`, but I haven't been able to get that to work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me split my answer into a *numpy* implementation and a *theano* implementation:

**Using numpy:**

```
def kpow(A, k):
     if k == 0:
         return np.identity(A.shape[0])
     if k == 1:
        return A
     else:
        return np.dot(A, kpow(A, k-1))
```

You could then get your `Apow` like this:

```
k = 5
A = np.array([[1, 1, 1],[2, 2, 2],[3, 3, 3]])
Apow = [kpow(A,i) for i in range(k)]
```

Of course, you could make this way more efficient by actually accumulating a list as you go along. The important thing to notice is the recurrence, how we use a previous result to compute the next.

**Using theano:**

First, let's define two symbolic variables for our `k` and matrix `M`:

```
k = T.iscalar('k')
M = T.dmatrix('M')
```

Next, let's define a recurrence function:

```
def recurrence(M, prev_result):
    return prev_result * M
```

Finally, it's time for the scan function:

```
result, updates = theano.scan(fn=recurrence,
                              outputs_info=T.identity_like(M),
                              non_sequences=M,
                              n_steps=k)
```

Now let's get some results:

```
A = np.array([[1, 1, 1],[2, 2, 2],[3, 3, 3]], dtype='int32')
kpow_theano = theano.function(inputs=[M,k], outputs=result)
Apow = [kpow_theano(A,10)[i] for i in range(10)]
```

I'm not sure how you would get the identity matrix at the front using theano. I guess you could prepend it to the list.